# Form factor and Guinier regime

Tags: condensed-matter, scattering

sorry for reposting.

I dont get why it is such a good idea to plot the logarithm of the form factor vs $Q^2$ in Guinier plots. It seems arbitrary to me.

Comment: Hi Tony. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted it and couldn't find it again. So now I tried to be more specific what exactly I don't understand and had to make a new one :)